# How to add an E-Mail filter for messages received in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I train Thunderbird's spam filter?](https://superuser.com/questions/78174/how-can-i-train-thunderbirds-spam-filter)

Ii'm using Thunderbird email client with a gmail account.

I need to somehow filter from client side (in Thunderbird) some content in emails.

For instance, if I receive msg which contain certain words I want it put directly into trash or another folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I train Thunderbird's spam filter?](http://superuser.com/questions/78174/how-can-i-train-thunderbirds-spam-filter) also see: [How to combine filter rules in message filters in Thunderbird to create more advanced filter criteria?](http://superuser.com/questions/51148/how-to-combine-filter-rules-in-message-filters-in-thunderbird-to-create-more-adv)